# Creating a javascript input box with text and image input areas

Tags: javascript, image, input, drag-and-drop, inputbox

I would like to create a composite input box where I can drag and drop an image and edit text using javascript. Any examples?

E.g. imagine a paragraph of text that can be edited, and the paragraph has image boxes on it where I can drag and drop images.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the image drag and drop...

[HTML5 Drag and Drop](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)